# Bell Notification status on a channel through the API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to change the status of the bell notification on a channel or at least view the status of the bell notification?

Answer (score 0):

That is out of scope for this api.   The YouTube API lets you control videos within your channel.

it is not intended to control things within your YouTube account link notification it simply doesn't contain that type of user information